# IEEETran `\markboth` Wrap Text

Tags: line-breaking, ieeetran

We are currently writing a journal paper using the IEEETran class. Typically we would use the `\markboth` command to add the journal name and paper title to odd and even pages. We are using Overleaf with the LaTeX engine being `pdfLaTeX` (or `Choose Automatically` whatever it picks for that).

In this particular paper, the paper title is quite long, so when adding the command:

```
\markboth{IEEE Journal Name }%
{Person \MakeLowercase{\textit{et al.}}: I am a journal paper name which is quite long. Of course I am not the actual name of the paper but I have an identical length in characters...}
```

The resulting odd page title is more than a page wide, but doesn't wrap meaning that it simply disappears off the side of the page.

I've tried adding a `\protect\\` new-line to the `\markboth` command, but that is simply ignored.

Is there any way to make long titles wrap onto a second line?

Comment: I would let the journal worry about details like that.  You could try putting the title into a \parbox, but then it would be too tall.

Comment: The best solution would be to cut off the end of the title and add etc. or yada yada yada ;-)